# Will a release upgrade take care of postgresql upgrade automatically?

Tags: upgrade, postgresql

I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 installation to 18.04. I installed postgresql 9.5 from the standard repositories and 18.04 includes postgresql 10.

Will the Ubuntu upgrader take care of postgresql stuff or do I have to upgrade the existing database manually/what exactly would be needed to upgrade?

Comment: If you use standard Ubuntu repositories for your software, the upgrade should automatically be handled by `do-release-upgrade` (or release upgrading).  This will not apply for non-Ubuntu repository software (eg. PPA's & other 3rd party sources).   It's possible that some minor packages are dropped (eg. the Unity desktop from 16.04 is no longer supported by Canonical or 'main' & is now in 'universe' or community-support; so some checking may still be required each release bump)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upgrade process had a few more steps. First, the new postgresql brought a new (empty) postgresql cluster with it. This needs to be removed: `sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main --stop` (`10` was my new postgresql version). Now the old cluster can be upgraded: `pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main` (`9.5` was my old version). Afterwards old packages can be removed: `sudo apt purge postgresql-contrib-9.5 postgresql-client-9.5 postgresql-9.5`.

See also: https://www.runrails.com/servers/upgrade-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

The newer PostgreSQL binaries/server will be installed, but you will still need to do a [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgupgrade.html) to upgrade your database